# Echo web framework binding FormFile

Tags: go, go-echo

I am using the Echo framework for a post endpoint that accepts the form data. I am using a Struct as a binding model to extract the form data. my binding model and upload handler code looks like below.

```
 type FormModel struct {
    ID string                `form:"ID"`
    FirstName string                `form:"FirstName"`
    File      *multipart.FileHeader `form:"myFileName"`
}

func (cs *handler) uploadForm(c echo.Context) error {
s := new(FormModel)
if err := c.Bind(s); err != nil {
    return nil
}

fileHandler, err := c.FormFile("myFileName")
```

I am able to get the form Values like ID and FirstName with binding. But I am not able to get the file during binding. I have to use `fileHandler, err := c.FormFile("myFileName")` to get the file. is there any way to get the file Info with in the binding model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Echo does not support binding multipart.Form.File data by default, you need to re-binder to implement the interface.

An additional layer of bind FormFile is encapsulated for echo Bind. If the attribute type of a structure pointer type is *multipart.FileHeader or []*multipart.FileHeader, this attribute will be set to the value of FormFile using reflection.

I probably realized the function. I haven't used echo and didn't test it, but the idea is correct.

last update: add example and fix code to build. Thanks @vicTROLLA for pointing out the `typeMultipartFileHeader` type definition error.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    "io/ioutil"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

var (
    typeMultipartFileHeader      = reflect.TypeOf((*multipart.FileHeader)(nil))
    typeMultipartSliceFileHeader = reflect.TypeOf(([]*multipart.FileHeader)(nil))
)

type File struct {
    File  *multipart.FileHeader   `form:"file"`
    Files []*multipart.FileHeader `form:"files"`
}

func main() {
    app := echo.New()
    // warp bind suppet bind FormFile
    app.Binder = NewBindFile(app.Binder)
    app.Any("/file", func(ctx echo.Context) error {
        var file File
        err := ctx.Bind(&file)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        readfile := func(file *multipart.FileHeader) {
            f, err := file.Open()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("open %s error: %s\n", file.Filename, err.Error())
                return
            }
            body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
            fmt.Printf("read file %s error: %v body: %s\n", file.Filename, err, body)
        }

        readfile(file.File)
        for _, file := range file.Files {
            readfile(file)
        }
        return err
    })

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)
        buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
        w := multipart.NewWriter(buf)
        part, _ := w.CreateFormFile("file", "file")
        part.Write([]byte("this one file"))
        part, _ = w.CreateFormFile("files", "files")
        part.Write([]byte("fils part 1"))
        part, _ = w.CreateFormFile("files", "files")
        part.Write([]byte("fils part 2"))
        part, _ = w.CreateFormFile("files", "files")
        part.Write([]byte("fils part 3"))
        part, _ = w.CreateFormFile("files", "files")
        part.Write([]byte("fils part 4"))
        w.Close()
        http.Post("http://localhost:1323/file", w.FormDataContentType(), buf)
    }()

    app.Start(":1323")
}

type BindFunc func(interface{}, echo.Context) error

func (fn BindFunc) Bind(i interface{}, ctx echo.Context) error {
    return fn(i, ctx)
}

func NewBindFile(b echo.Binder) echo.Binder {
    return BindFunc(func(i interface{}, ctx echo.Context) error {
        err := b.Bind(i, ctx)
        if err == nil {
            ctype := ctx.Request().Header.Get(echo.HeaderContentType)
            // if bind form
            if strings.HasPrefix(ctype, echo.MIMEApplicationForm) || strings.HasPrefix(ctype, echo.MIMEMultipartForm) {
                // get form files
                var form *multipart.Form
                form, err = ctx.MultipartForm()
                if err == nil {
                    err = EchoBindFile(i, ctx, form.File)
                }
            }
        }
        return err
    })
}

func EchoBindFile(i interface{}, ctx echo.Context, files map[string][]*multipart.FileHeader) error {
    iValue := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(i))
    // check bind type is struct pointer
    if iValue.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return fmt.Errorf("BindFile input not is struct pointer, indirect type is %s", iValue.Type().String())
    }

    iType := iValue.Type()
    for i := 0; i < iType.NumField(); i++ {
        fType := iType.Field(i)
        // check canset field
        fValue := iValue.Field(i)
        if !fValue.CanSet() {
            continue
        }
        // revc type must *multipart.FileHeader or []*multipart.FileHeader
        switch fType.Type {
        case typeMultipartFileHeader:
            file := getFiles(files, fType.Name, fType.Tag.Get("form"))
            if len(file) > 0 {
                fValue.Set(reflect.ValueOf(file[0]))
            }
        case typeMultipartSliceFileHeader:
            file := getFiles(files, fType.Name, fType.Tag.Get("form"))
            if len(file) > 0 {
                fValue.Set(reflect.ValueOf(file))
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func getFiles(files map[string][]*multipart.FileHeader, names ...string) []*multipart.FileHeader {
    for _, name := range names {
        file, ok := files[name]
        if ok {
            return file
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Just a note here, you ned to remove `.Elem()` from typeMultipartFileHeader, and typeMultipartSliceFileHeader. Theres a few other minor syntax changes. Without removing Elem(), the switch case assumes (which doesn't contain a default) will try to assign the value on as if it were typeMultipartSliceFileHeader and panic.